# Debugger just stops on HttpClient.GetAsync call from a test

Tags: c#, asynchronous, get, dotnet-httpclient

I'm basing myself on this sample:

[async-example-with-HttpClient](http://rextester.com/discussion/XPKY90132/async-example-with-HttpClient)

I have the exact same code, which I'm running from a test:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Stuff>> GetStuff()
{
    var r = await DownloadPage("http://stackoverflow.com");
}

static async Task<string> DownloadPage(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var r = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url)))
        {
            string result = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. The debugger just stops on the await `client.GetAsync(new Uri(url))` call.

There's no exception being thrown, there's nothing in the Visual Studio output window.

I have Fiddler open with all sessions cleared, I see nothing changing on doing that GET call.

I have nothing to go on why this doesn't work.

> Any ideas on why this doesn't work and what I can do?

**Update**

This does partly work when called from an API, not from the xunit test I was starting with. But, when called from the API the response from the backend isn't received and the caller keeps waiting forever:

[image]

If I keep the code entirely on the API side, so no calls to any deeper dependencies, everything works. Context switching must be causing issues somehow.

Comment: Is this code in an `asp.net` process?

Comment: Within normal C# it works - i've tested your exact code 10 seconds ago

Comment: Can you show the asp.net code where these methods get called. I'm guessing you are making a synchronous call somewhere.

Comment: It's code in a class library called from a test. But eventually it will be called from a Web API 2.

Comment: @Twometer: I've just tried directly from the api, it works in there as well. So why not from the test ...

Comment: Does the test prevent network requests, and you just didn't wait for the `Timeout` exception to be thrown?

Comment: @Twometer: I haven't set it up to prevent requests (wouldn't know how either). I'm using xunit.